# Should the “duplicate of” be reversed for these two questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[PHP Pass by reference in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach) is currently marked as a duplicate of [Strange behavior Of foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach). The former is a better asked, more upvoted, and older. Should the duplicate of be reversed for these two questions?

Comment: Ah... the person who answered the later question close voted the earlier one with a gold badge dupe hammer. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Reverse it, I'd say... The former seems like the better dupe target.

Comment: Does one have an answer that is marginally better than the other? I can't really judge that myself. IMO dupe links should bring people to the better answers, not necessarily the better questions.

Comment: Probably worth considering merging the questions.

Comment: Just take into account that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4966352) is also pointing at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4969243. Furthermore, it may be worth it to also mark https://stackoverflow.com/q/8220399 as a duplicate of either of the two. This is what I found in a couple of minutes. Ugh, [tag:php] ...

Comment: Just burninate the tag, problem solved.

Comment: @Will Don't forget to circle it free-handedly after 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Reading your comment gave me the impression it was done concurrently, which makes it seem a lot worse. He answered it in 2011 and only just hammered the first one, which doesn't seem nearly as unreasonable. Figured that was worth pointing out in case others assume incorrectly like I did.

Comment: @TemporalWolf "He answered it in 2011 and only just hammered the first one". Did you have a different impression initially? I still feel it's questionable to hammer an older and more upvoted question to a question where he is the top answer, although I'm not making any assumptions on his intent here.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I agree, that's not as bad as answering a brand new question, then immediately closing an older question as a dupe of that fresh new post. Still, at some point he made the decision to close a perfectly good older question as a duplicate of one he answered. Not horrible behavior, but a little bit questionable.

Comment: @Goose I did, which I mentioned as the reason for the clarification. And I agree the dupe direction should probably be reversed. I just had a much harder time giving the hammerer in question the benefit of the doubt before I saw the dates and I didn't want anyone else to make that poor assumption. It's increasingly looking like the intent was to build a canonical answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's older or not. What matters is which one is better asked, and even though I don't know anything about PHP, I agree that the older one looks like it is better asked, so I agree that the duplicates should be reversed.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Better asked and better answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of those rare cases where duplication isn't the answer, as much as a merge of the two questions. The problem is identical, but let's look at the answers for a second. In the older one, the accepted answer isn't all that great. It answers the question but doesn't break down *why* it does that.

Mark Baker's answer in the second one was posted on `Feb 11 '11`. There's a similar answer explaining the *why* in the first posted on `Mar 1 '13` (you'll note this answer has more upvotes than the accepted answer, and rightfully so).

There's only 2 answers in the newer question as well. Merge and reopen it